# How do I mock a class instance and assign attributes to that instance using mocker.patch.object() and pytest-mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to unit test a module (using pytest and pytest-mock) and I would like to create a mocked instance of a class with certain values for its attributes to be used in a @pytest.fixture

I think I've finally found what I'm looking for in [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and [autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing) but I don't understand what the arguments are supposed to be, specifically 'attribute'

```
patch.object(target, attribute, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False,
spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)
```

> patch the named member (attribute) on an object (target) with a mock object.

I tried searching for patch.object() examples but I'm only seeing use cases related to mocking the return values for methods in a class.

Like in this [example,](https://queirozf.com/entries/python-unittest-examples-mocking-and-patching#patch-object-of-class) a method is passed as the 'attribute' argument to patch.object().

Any help or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An example would be the method that you're trying to test.

So, if I wanted to check to see if `MyClass.method_a` was called, I would do:

```
from .functions import MyClass  # import MyClass from wherever 
                                # it is used in the module.


with patch.object(MyClass, 'method_a') as mocked_myclass:
    function_that_called_myclass_method_a()

mocked_myclass.assert_called()
```